# How to swap the postgres schema attribute for a sqlalchemy metadata

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We are using SQLAlchemy in conjunction with postgres and i am trying to switch the postgres schema i am working on dynamically so that every following sql command take into account the new schema. We are using a declarative base model and i am struggling to make the table class switch their schema when needed.

Doing

```
sa_metadata.schema = 'new_schema'
for table in sa_metadata.tables.keys():
    table.metadata = 'new_schema'
```

Does not work properly as some postgres object (sequence, Enum) have their own schema attribute and I don't want to loop over every objects within the tables to change the schema. I looked at [Table.tometadata](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.tometadata) but failed to use properly.

Does someone know if this kind of stuff is possible ? Or is it silly of me to have two schemas with the same tables in each ?

EDIT:

So basically i need to recreate a metadata and new tables associated with it. Problem is that all my table definitions are on another python file that gets read at import time. Something that contains:

```
SaBaseClass = declarative_base()
SaBaseClass.schema = settings.DB.schema

TableA(SaBaseClass): 
__tablename__ = 'leg'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
col = Column(Enum('a', 'b', 'c', inherit_schema=True))
```

Based on this, how can i make sure that every other python module that have imported TableA are using the correct schema whenever i want to change the whole metadata's schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the inherit_schema flag on the Enum:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, Enum

m1 = MetaData()

t1 = Table(
    't1',
    m1, Column('a', Integer),
    Column('b', Enum('a', 'b', 'c', inherit_schema=True)), schema='x')

m2 = MetaData()
t2 = t1.tometadata(m2, schema='y')

print t2.schema
print t2.c.b.type.schema
```

Comment: That what i did but when i am working with the ORM part, i can't figured it out...

Comment: there's not right now a simple way to re-map all your classes to a different schema.  this is something that would be better handled by the context taking place while you work with the database, which is addressed by an upcoming feature.  For now, your best bet is to leave schema absent, and when working with the model, set the [search path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) on either your engine in use or on the connection used with the session.